# Test Cordova/ PhoneGap app on Ipad

Tags: ios, cordova, ios-simulator, phonegap-build

just wondering how you would test a cordova app onto an iPad without registering for the developer program. Xcode, which manages the simulator now allows you to do so without registering for the developer program. However, since I am not developing the app in Xcode, I wondered if this is possible at all.

[image]

Comment: You will still need to build the with Xcode for a build for iOS, so you will also be able to run you cordova app on your device via Xcode

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly also look at the [PhoneGap Developer App](http://app.phonegap.com/), depending on what your application does.